# Message: Call to undefined function cal_days_in_month()

Tags: php

Need help to solve the following error in PHP

> Message: Call to undefined function cal_days_in_month()

```
$currentdate = date('2023-07');
$convertmoon = date('Y-m', strtotime($currentdate));
$convertdate = strtotime($currentdate);

// Current Year, Month, Date
$get_yy_thismonth = date('Y', strtotime($currentdate));
$get_mf_thismonth = date('F', strtotime($currentdate));
$get_mm_thismonth = date('m', strtotime($currentdate));
$get_mn_thismonth = date('n', strtotime($currentdate));
$get_dt_thismonth = date('d', strtotime($currentdate));
$get_dy_thismonth = date('D', strtotime($currentdate));
$get_dz_thismonth = date('t', strtotime($currentdate));

$get_nn_thismonth = date('Y-m', strtotime($currentdate));
$totaldays_of_thismonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $get_mm_thismonth, $get_yy_thismonth);
```

Comment: Your PHP might not have this extension installed. See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/calendar.installation.php You can check your installation with [phpinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php).

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge it is installed but not enabled. Locate your php.ini fie and un-comment the line `;extension=calendar` by removing the semi-colon at the beginning

Comment: I forgot to mention you need to restart your web server after doing the above